# I am trying to display the title of the song in the pop category

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE artists (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT,
    country TEXT,
    genre TEXT);

INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Taylor Swift", "US", "Pop");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Led Zeppelin", "US", "Hard rock");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("ABBA", "Sweden", "Disco");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Queen", "UK", "Rock");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Celine Dion", "Canada", "Pop");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Meatloaf", "US", "Hard rock");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Garth Brooks", "US", "Country");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Shania Twain", "Canada", "Country");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Rihanna", "US", "Pop");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Guns N' Roses", "US", "Hard rock");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Gloria Estefan", "US", "Pop");
INSERT INTO artists (name, country, genre)
    VALUES ("Bob Marley", "Jamaica", "Reggae");

CREATE TABLE songs (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    artist TEXT,
    title TEXT);

INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("Taylor Swift", "Shake it off");
INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("Rihanna", "Stay");
INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("Celine Dion", "My heart will go on");
INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("Celine Dion", "A new day has come");
INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("Shania Twain", "Party for two");
INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("Gloria Estefan", "Conga");
INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("Led Zeppelin", "Stairway to heaven");
INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("ABBA", "Mamma mia");
INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("Queen", "Bicycle Race");
INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("Queen", "Bohemian Rhapsody");
INSERT INTO songs (artist, title)
    VALUES ("Guns N' Roses", "Don't cry");
```

What I'm trying to do is to display the title of the song in the pop category

This is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM artists 
WHERE genre == "Pop" id IN(SELECT id title FROM songs);
```

Can you help me please

Comment: Yes, and what's the problem here? If you're using `==` to compare things in SQL, you really need to brush up on basic SQL syntax.

Comment: Failing to read the documentation is really the problem you're having here.

Comment: Look into normalisation as well... will save you from having to duplicate artist names in the `songs` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi here is the query you need:

```
SELECT s.title 
FROM songs s
INNER JOIN artists a
ON s.artist = a.name AND a.genre = 'Pop';
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75ca3/5) for that to see how it work.

GL!

Comment: @rychrist88 you're welcome :) I'm glead that I could help. If you find my answer usefull please mark it I'll appreciate that... GL

Comment: Usually `JOIN` is better than a sub-`SELECT`. I like this one better.

Comment: @rychrist88 yes it is but the good thing is that you have options :) also you can upvote both answer there is no law against it. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT title
FROM songs
WHERE artist IN
    (SELECT name
     FROM artists
     WHERE genre = 'Pop')
```

Comment: I tried this before and it's giving me all the songs instead of just the ones under the pop category

Comment: whoops, misread the table definition, that should be "SELECT Name" instead of "SELECT artist" on the inner part.

Comment: One of the quirks of subqueries is that if they're invalid it's like returning null, which on an "IN" will mean no restriction at all.